# Deserializing object leads to null variables inside object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a object in C#, using NewtonSoft framework fro json handling. This is my code.

**Brief Explanation**

Essentially, I am creating a api call to the login endpoint to authenticate my user (this works), I need to extract the bearer token from the api call which returns a **UserResponseDTO**, this DTO contains the AuthToken attribute which I need to access, to pass my test cases.

Now this is the code of my test case.

```cs
[Fact]
public async void SuccessfulGetUserDetails()
{
    //Arrange
    //Arrange
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(success); //Prepare payload
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); //Set type to Json

    //Act
    var result = await _client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/Security/login", byteContent); //Send Request
    var jsonstring = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //Get JSON String

    UserResponseDTO dto = new UserResponseDTO();

    dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponseDTO>(jsonstring); //Deserialize
    Assert.Equal(dto,null);
}
```

Now my last Assert check is to check if the DTO object is null....its not, but the values inside it are.

This is the UserResponseDTO

```cs
public class UserResponseDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
    public List<Menus> Menus { get; set;}
}

public class UserRole
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual List<RolePermission> RolePermission { get; set; }
    public List<RoleMenu> RoleMenu { get; set; }
}

public class RoleMenu
{
    public int RoleMenuId { get; set; }

    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
}

public class RolePermission
{
    public int RolePermissionId { get; set; }

    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string Urlprefix { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsParent { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int? ParentMenu { get; set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }

    public string CssClass { get; set; }
}

public class Menus
{
    public bool isExternal { get; set; }
    public string cssClass { get; set; }
    public string routeLink { get; set; }
    public string menuText { get; set; }
    public List<SubMenuItems> subMenuItems { get; set; } = new List<SubMenuItems>();
}

public class SubMenuItems
{
    public string routeLink { get; set; }
    public string menuText { get; set; }
    public string cssClass { get; set; }
}
```

Last but not least,  I have noticed

**THE CORRECT** Json String is being returned however it is not being deserializd properly into a UserResponseDTO Object. And the values inside the DTO are all null.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

He is the JSON that is being returned in JSON String

[image: JSON Output shown in JsonString variable]

Code of JSON as requested

```
 "loginResponse": "Authenticated",
"userDetails": {
    "userId": 3,
    "authToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNjIzMDM2OTkxLCJleHAiOjE2MjMwNDA1OTEsImlhdCI6MTYyMzAzNjk5MX0.wwIJ93syFnpcvjtw_Sj1s4uCtYPUtoROmwF3jkDZWo0",
    "userName": "admin",
    "fullName": "REDACTED",
    "unit": null,
    "isActive": "1",
    "mobile": "+REDACTED",
    "email": "REDACTED",
    "userRole": [
        {
            "role": {
                "roleId": 1,
                "applicationId": 1,
                "roleDescription": "Administrator",
                "rolePermission": [
                    {
                        "rolePermissionId": 0,
                        "permission": {
                            "permissionId": 1,
                            "name": "CanApprove"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "rolePermissionId": 0,
                        "permission": {
                            "permissionId": 2,
                            "name": "CanReject"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "rolePermissionId": 0,
                        "permission": {
                            "permissionId": 3,
                            "name": "CanReview"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "rolePermissionId": 0,
                        "permission": {
                            "permissionId": 4,
                            "name": "CanDownload"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "roleMenu": [
                    {
                        "roleMenuId": 1,
                        "isDefault": true,
                        "menu": {
                            "menuId": 1,
                            "urlprefix": "UI",
                            "url": "worklist",
                            "description": "Menu",
                            "isParent": true,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "parentMenu": null,
                            "htmlBody": "<li><a href=\"URL\"><i class=\"fa fa-cog\"></i><span class=\"nav-label\">HEADING</span></a></li>",
                            "cssClass": "receipt"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "roleMenuId": 2,
                        "isDefault": false,
                        "menu": {
                            "menuId": 2,
                            "urlprefix": "UI",
                            "url": "reports",
                            "description": "Link 1",
                            "isParent": false,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "parentMenu": 1,
                            "htmlBody": "<li><a href=\"URL\"><i class=\"fa fa-plug\"></i><span class=\"nav-label\">HEADING</span></a></li>",
                            "cssClass": "fact_check"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "roleMenuId": 3,
                        "isDefault": false,
                        "menu": {
                            "menuId": 3,
                            "urlprefix": "UI",
                            "url": "generatefile",
                            "description": "Link 2",
                            "isParent": false,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "parentMenu": 1,
                            "htmlBody": "<li><a href=\"URL\">HEADING</a></li>",
                            "cssClass": "file_present"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "roleMenuId": 9,
                        "isDefault": false,
                        "menu": {
                            "menuId": 4,
                            "urlprefix": "UI",
                            "url": "globalsearch",
                            "description": "Global Search",
                            "isParent": true,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "parentMenu": null,
                            "htmlBody": "<li><a href=\"URL\">HEADING</a></li>",
                            "cssClass": "search"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "menus": [
        {
            "isExternal": false,
            "cssClass": "receipt",
            "routeLink": "worklist",
            "menuText": "Menu",
            "subMenuItems": [
                {
                    "routeLink": "reports",
                    "menuText": "Link 1",
                    "cssClass": "fact_check"
                },
                {
                    "routeLink": "generatefile",
                    "menuText": "Link 2",
                    "cssClass": "file_present"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "isExternal": false,
            "cssClass": "search",
            "routeLink": "globalsearch",
            "menuText": "Global Search",
            "subMenuItems": []
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Step 1 - show us the actual JSON.

Comment: `THE CORRECT Json String is being returned` There is almost 100% correlation between that statement, and the fact that the JSON doesn't match the class structure. Please share the actual JSON.

Comment: 1000 apologies i have done that

Comment: @TheNotoriousCoder post the JSON document as a **string**. Images of property trees aren't JSON and can't be deserialized.

Comment: In fact, save your time. Throw away your existing classes, since they are completely wrong (as suspected). Go to https://app.quicktype.io/ . Paste in the JSON. Use the classes it generates.

Comment: Or, copy the JSON string and in Visual Studio right-click in an empty C# file and select `Paste Special > As Json classes`. The property names have inconsistent casing. JSON is case-sensitive. While you can configurer JSON.NET to use Camel- or Pascal-casing, it can't handle mixed casing out-of-the-box

Comment: I have sent the JSON I am extremely sorry for the hassle, I usually dont post often so am not familiar with best practice.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Your json does not match the `UserResponseDTO`, you need add matched model like:

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public string LoginResponse { get; set; }
    public UserResponseDTO UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not want to add the response model, you need modify the json string to read `userDetails`:

```
//1. get the json string
    string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");
//2. convert to JObject
    var model = JObject.Parse(json);
//3. get userDetails json string
    string jsonstring = model["userDetails"].ToString();

    UserResponseDTO dto = new UserResponseDTO();
    dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserResponseDTO>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: This answer did not work, I am getting the json string with "\r\n" i think that is causing a problem, will update you tomorrow.